# Numero aleatorio numa faixa de números com probabilidades pre-definidas

Tags: javascript

Preciso criar uma especie de roleta onde sai um prémio aleatório tendo em conta:

- o tipo de prémio, por exemplo 5 prémios diferentes uns melhores do que outros
- Quanto melhor for o prémio mais baixa a probabilidade de sair
- o stock dos prémios, ter em conta se o prémio ainda esta em stock

Estava a pensar organizar os valores assim:

```
var premios = [
        { 'tipo': 'premio1', 'stock': 40, 'probabilidade': 0.5 },
        { 'tipo': 'premio2', 'stock': 40, 'probabilidade': 0.5 },
        { 'tipo': 'premio3', 'stock': 30, 'probabilidade': 0.4 },
        { 'tipo': 'premio4', 'stock': 10, 'probabilidade': 0.2 },
        { 'tipo': 'premio5', 'stock': 5, 'probabilidade': 0.1 }
    ];
```

Estive a experimentar varias coisas, acho que cheguei perto de uma solução mas não esta a funcionar a 100%, as probabilidades não batem certo.
Estou um pouco perdido, alguém pode ajudar?

```
function RandomProb () {
    var s = 0,
        pcnt = premios.length, 
        num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 - 1 + 1)) + 1;

    for (var i = 0; i < pcnt; ++i) {

        range = premios[i].probabilidade * 1000;

        if (num < 1000-range && premios[i].stock) {
            premios[i].stock--; 
            return premios[i].tipo;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Acho que seria mais fácil criar o range nos valores, por exemplo de [0-2000] Prêmio 1, [4000- 4100] Prêmio 4, você pode dar uma olhada nesta outra [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39601/sorteando-strings-de-uma-array-com-peso)

Comment: Obrigado @MarcoGiovanni, estou a perceber. acho que pode ser uma boa ideia.

Comment: simplesmente duplica os valores com maior probabilidade de aparecer ou triplica quadripila dependendo da importam cia e pega por rand, vai da na mesma o cod é menor e mais facil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de muito matutar e graças a ajuda dos comentários consegui chegar a uma solução funcional:

```
var premios = [
        { 'tipo': 'premio1', 'stock': 50, 'probabilidade': 5 },
        { 'tipo': 'premio2', 'stock': 40, 'probabilidade': 4 },
        { 'tipo': 'premio3', 'stock': 30, 'probabilidade': 3 },
        { 'tipo': 'premio4', 'stock': 20, 'probabilidade': 2 },
        { 'tipo': 'premio5', 'stock': 10, 'probabilidade': 1 }
    ];


function RandomProb () {

    var aSorteio = [];

    premios = $.grep(premios, function(e){ 
        return e.stock > 0; 
    });

    premios.forEach(function (p,i) { 
            var r = Math.floor(p.probabilidade/1);
            for (var i = 0; i < r; i++) { 
                aSorteio.push(i);
            }
    });

    var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * aSorteio.length),
    p = aSorteio[g];
    if(premios[p]!=undefined){ 
        premios[p].stock--;
        return premios[p].tipo;
    }
};
```

Depois, reparei que não é necessário ter o valor probabilidade uma vez que no fim do stock o prémio já não sai.
Por isso a solução final ficou assim:

```
var premios = [
        { 'tipo': 'premio1', 'stock': 50 },
        { 'tipo': 'premio2', 'stock': 40 },
        { 'tipo': 'premio3', 'stock': 30 },
        { 'tipo': 'premio4', 'stock': 20 },
        { 'tipo': 'premio5', 'stock': 10 }
    ];


function RandomProb () {

    premios = $.grep(premios, function(e){ 
        return e.stock > 0; 
    });

    var p = Math.floor(Math.random() * premios.length);

    if(premios[p]!=undefined){ 
        premios[p].stock--;
        return premios[p].tipo;
    }
};
```