# Sistema de sorteio

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou pretendendo fazer um sistema de sorteios em meu site.
Li algumas perguntas (inclusive uma que me agradou muito [que foi esta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39601/sorteando-strings-de-uma-array-com-peso)) e notei pessoas dizendo que Cidades X poderiam nunca ser sorteadas, enquanto Cidades Y sorteadas várias vezes.

A questão é: qual a confiabilidade dos seguintes casos de sorteio?

## Sorteio pelo SQL

```
SELECT `id` FROM `tabela` ORDER BY RAND () LIMIT 1;
```

## Sorteio pelo PHP

```
<php
$minimo = 0;
$maximo = 10000;
$sorteio = rand($minimo, $maximo);
echo $sorteio;
?>
```

Pensei em algumas fórmulas para incluir o fator **peso** no meu sorteio, mas percebi que seria mais fácil apenas registrar o mesmo item do sorteio uma outra vez.

De fato, a questão final é: como fazer um sorteio de pessoas, atribuindo a algumas destas, vantagens 
**Exemplo:** João tem 60% de chance de ser escolhido, Maria tem 40% de chance) - É melhor por o nome de joão 6 vezes no sorteio e por o nome de maria 4 vezes ou há alguma solução definida?

Comment: Acredito que o problema seja parecido com [este](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205446/5878). Veja se a resposta dada pelo Inkeliz te ajuda.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada

Comment: No [so] há esta [resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11872928/1452488) também que pode ser útil.

Answer (score 2):

Temos que entender um pouco de estatística para chegar a questão final.

Um experimento é considerado aleatório quando suas ocorrências podem apresentar resultados diferentes. Um exemplo disso acontece ao lançarmos uma moeda que possua faces distintas, sendo uma cara e outra coroa. O resultado desse lançamento é imprevisível, pois não há como saber qual a face que ficará para cima.

O espaço amostral (S) determina as possibilidades possíveis de resultados. No caso do lançamento de uma moeda o conjunto do espaço amostral é dado por: S = {cara, coroa}, isso porque são as duas únicas respostas possíveis para esse experimento aleatório.

Na probabilidade a ocorrência de um fato ou situação é chamado de evento. Sendo assim, ao lançarmos uma moeda estamos estabelecendo a ocorrência do evento. Temos então que, qualquer subconjunto do espaço amostral deve ser considerado um evento. Um exemplo pode acontecer ao lançarmos uma moeda três vezes, é obtermos como resultado do evento o seguinte conjunto:

E = {Cara, Coroa, Cara}

A razão de probabilidade é dada pelas possibilidades de um evento ocorrer levando em consideração o seu espaço amostral. Essa razão que é uma fração é igual ao número de elementos do evento (numerador) sobre o número de elementos do espaço amostral (denominador). Considera os seguintes elementos:

```
E é um evento.
n(E) é o número de elementos do evento.
S é espaço amostral.
n(S) é a quantidade de elementos do espaço amostral.
A Razão de probabilidade é dada por:

         n(E)
  P(E)= -----     sendo n(S) ≠ 0
         n(S)
```

Com relação a sua questão teríamos:

```
 S = {João, João, João, João, João, João, Maria, Maria, Maria, Maria}
 S =10
```

No caso do João

```
 E = {João, João, João, João, João, João}
 E = 6

 P(João) = 6/10 = 60%
```

E no caso Maria

```
 E = {Maria, Maria, Maria, Maria}
 E=4

 P(Maria) = 4/10 = 40%
```

A probabilidade normalmente é representa por um fração, cujo seu valor sempre estará entre 0 e 1.

Podemos também representar a probabilidade com um número decimal ou em forma de porcentagem

Portanto João terá 60% de probabilidade contra 40% de Maria em um número de elementos igual a 10.

Se esse numero de elementos forem, por exemplo, 1000, sendo 6 de João e 4 de Maria teríamos:

P(João) = 6/1000  = 0,6%

P(Maria) = 4/1000 = 0,4%

Comment: Quando você só está procurando conteúdo aleatório no Stack e se depara com esta aula... hahaha