# Como faço pra percorrer os dados de um array, para realizar um sorteio com proporções de chances?

Tags: php, php-7

Seguinte galera, eu estava estudando como eu poderia criar uma pequena aplicação de sorteio que fosse simples e justo e ao mesmo tempo tenha probabilidades, em minhas pesquisas encontrei diversos modos de fazer uma escolha aleatória dos dados armazenados dentro de um array, usando os comandos rand(), mt_rand() e array_rand() e até mesmo usando a função shuffle() para ajudar embaralhando.

Ai é que entra a questão, para fazer um sorteio normal onde os dados tem a mesma chance (Probabilidade) de ser escolhido essas funções por si só já é o suficiente e funciona muito bem, porém eu gostaria de saber como eu poderia adicionar o elemento "Chance ou Probabilidade" que um dado armazenado dentro do array ou no Banco de Dados pode ser escolhido

Vou tentar dar um exemplo do que eu gostaria de tentar fazer:

1 - Exemplo que possui chances iguais:

```
<?php
//Variável que armazena os dados do array
$escolher = array("Arroz", "Feijão", "Macarrão", "Pizza", "Hamburguer");

//Variável que irá armazenar o elemento escolhido aleatóriamente
$resultado = array_rand($escolher);

//Imprimindo o Resultado na tela
echo 'O Alimento escolhido foi: ' . $resultado; //(Arroz)
?>
```

2 - Exemplo que adiciona quantidade de chances ou probabilidades de um elemento ser escolhido:

```
<?php
/*
Variável que armazena os dados do array,
repetindo os dados de acordo com o numero de chances que cada um tem de ser escolhido sendo,
Arroz = 2, Feijão = 1, Macarrão = 4, Pizza = 3, Hamburguer = 4
*/
$escolher = array(
"Arroz", "Arroz",
"Feijão",
"Macarrão", "Macarrão", "Macarrão", "Macarrão",
"Pizza", "Pizza", "Pizza",
"Hamburguer", "Hamburguer", "Hamburguer", "Hamburguer"
);

//Variável que irá armazenar o elemento escolhido aleatóriamente
$resultado = array_rand($escolher);

//Imprimindo o Resultado na tela
echo 'O Alimento escolhido foi: ' . $resultado; //(Macarrão)
?>
```

Bem, os dois exemplos funcionam retornando um resultado aleatório, mas no caso não sei se a repetição que ocorre no exemplo 2 é confiável, e eu gostaria de fazer o segundo exemplo de uma forma em que eu não precise ficar repetindo a mesma informação diversas vezes dentro do array para aumentar ou diminuir as chances dele ser escolhido, gostaria de fazer algo em que eu pude-se informar as probabilidades através de números, e informar qual é a chance que cada elemento tem, e assim poder manipular quem tem mais prioridade de ser escolhido e quem tem menos prioridade.

Eu estava dando uma olhada nesses artigos aqui do SOpt, porém eu fiquei mais perdido do que cego em tiroteio, talvez devido ao meu nível de conhecimento que não é muito elevado, por isso gostaria da ajuda de vocês, agradeço dese já.

Esses são os links dos artigos que eu citei:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/206164/sistema-de-sorteio

[Sorteando strings de uma array com peso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39601/sorteando-strings-de-uma-array-com-peso)

Comment: O problema é confuso porque ele fala em pesos, mas não tem nada aí que deveria ter pesos, são itens isolados. Se o problema não está bem definido a solução nunca será certa, primeiro defina ele corretamente.

Comment: O array com mesma chave? Isso nunca vai dar certo

Comment: Peso que eu digo é como se fosse probabilidades, ou chances. No caso um item ter mais chances do que outro item de ser escolhido.

Comment: Vou repetir o que eu disse, nada no seu código indica ter isso que está dizendo, por isso fica difícil dar uma solução adequada, por exemplo, se tivesse pesos de um ser escolhido mais que outro a resposta já dada estaria errada, e provavelmente está e não ajudou nada, por isso devemos só responder quando a pergunta está clara.

Comment: Bacana, eu entendo o que você quer dizer. Vou tentar reformular a pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que uma melhor abordagem seria transformar esses pesos em índices assim realizar um random para verificar o intervalo sorteado.

```php
    <?php

        $weights = ['arroz' => 2,  "feijao" => 1, "macarrao" => 4, "pizza" => 3, "hamburguer" => 4];
        $max = array_sum($weights);
        $sortIndex = rand(1, $max);
        $sort = null;
        $offset = 0;

        foreach ($weights as $key => $value) {
            $offset += $value;
            if ($sortIndex <= $offset) {
                $sort = $key;
                break;
            }
        }

        echo $sort;
```

Comment: Eu não tinha parado para pensar em usar o nome como chave, dessa maneira funcionou, irei parar e e estudar o que acontece em cada linha, para entender todo o conceito por trás. Muito Obrigado, Aprendi mais uma.

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia, espero ajudar.

seu exemplo:

```
$tarefas = array(
    3 => 'Comer Pizza';
    1 => 'Comer Hamburguer'; 
    5 => 'Comer Arroz com Feijao';
    3 => 'Comer Macarrao';
    1 => 'Comer Pao com Mortadela';
);

$min = 1;  //Valor Minimo
$max = 13; //Máximo com base na soma das Chaves do array

$x = mt_rand($min, $max);
echo $tarefas[$x];

$x = mt_rand(1, 13); //Saída Ex: 5
echo $tarefas[5]; // Comer Arroz com Feijao
```

Realize as alterações abaixo para te ajudar, expliquei no código:

```
<?php
    $tarefas = array(
        3 => 'Comer Pizza',
        1 => 'Comer Hamburguer', 
        5 => 'Comer Arroz com Feijao',
        3 => 'Comer Macarrao',
        1 => 'Comer Pao com Mortadela'
    );

    //1 - Organizar as chaves, com isto, não havendo mais repetidos e sim distintos.
    $tarefasN = array_values($tarefas);

    //2 - array_rand, escolhe já de forma aleatoria um ou mais indice no array
    $aleatorio = array_rand($tarefasN, 1); //aonde está 1 vc pode usar para ter retorno, exemplo, se quer 2 retornos, ou 3, 4 e assim por diante

    echo $aleatorio . ' - '; //gera índice aleatório

    echo $tarefasN[$aleatorio]; // retorno já com o array organizado
```

Comment: Opa Leandro, então fiz uns testes, e o que acontece, quando uso o array_rand ele faz uma escolha aleatória dentro do array, isso por si só ja serve como um sorteio, porém eu preciso que a variante Chances tenha peso na hora da escolha. Seguindo o modelo que você me mostrou o sorteio está escolhendo mais vezes "Comer Pao com Mortadela" que tem 1 de peso (chance) enquanto o "Comer Pizza" que tem 3 de peso (chance) não está sendo sorteado. Não sei se entendeu o que esta acontecendo, E obrigado por estar tentando me ajudar.